# eclipse STS 4.7 with devstyle explorer browser folder arrows are dark/black and can't be seen in dark mode

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

installed eclipse STS 4.7.  then installed dev style plugin from marketplace. Set it to dark mode with intelliJ dark theme. Now I can't see the side arrows.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STS 4.7 is based on Eclipse 2020-06 and there are known issues with Dark themes in this version of Eclipse. The good news is that we already have a fix for it in DevStyle. The update will be available early next week but you can try a patch and see if the fix will work for you. To try it you can follow the instructions in my last comment [here](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/devstyle-eclipse-2020-06/)

Comment: This is still happening for me, when i download a fresh copy of STS 4.8.1 (bundled with its own JRE) and install devstyle.  I'm on windows10 1803, laptop with integrated GPU.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by downgrading to Eclipse 2020.03 (Non STS Edition)

Comment: I cross a similar issue with Eclipse 2020-12 on Win 7, reported at https://s.apache.org/hnk7w